# Unity for UWP - Mono.Cecil.AssemblyResolutionException: Failed to resolve assembly: 'Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract

Tags: unity-game-engine, uwp

I am using Unity 5.6.0f3 and Visual Studio Community 2017, version 15.3.2.

I have exported a project for UWP, Unity editor has created a solution for UWP which should be opened with Visual Studio.

When building this project in Visual Studio, regardless whether for x64 or x32 configuration, I get the following exception:

```
Mono.Cecil.AssemblyResolutionException: Failed to resolve assembly: 'Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
at Mono.Cecil.BaseAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference name, ReaderParameters parameters)
at Mono.Cecil.DefaultAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference name)
at Mono.Cecil.MetadataResolver.Resolve(TypeReference type)
at Mono.Cecil.TypeReference.Resolve()
at Mono.Cecil.Mixin.CheckedResolve(TypeReference self)
at Mono.Cecil.MetadataBuilder.GetConstantType(TypeReference constant_type, Object constant)
at Mono.Cecil.MetadataBuilder.AddConstant(IConstantProvider owner, TypeReference type)
at Mono.Cecil.MetadataBuilder.AddField(FieldDefinition field)
at Mono.Cecil.MetadataBuilder.AddFields(TypeDefinition type)
at Mono.Cecil.MetadataBuilder.AddType(TypeDefinition type)
at Mono.Cecil.MetadataBuilder.AddTypeDefs()
at Mono.Cecil.MetadataBuilder.BuildTypes()
at Mono.Cecil.MetadataBuilder.BuildModule()
at Mono.Cecil.ModuleWriter.<>c.<BuildMetadata>b__1_0(MetadataBuilder builder, MetadataReader _)
at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.Read[TItem,TRet](TItem item, Func`3 read)
at Mono.Cecil.ModuleWriter.WriteModuleTo(ModuleDefinition module, Stream stream, WriterParameters parameters)
at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.Write(String fileName, WriterParameters parameters)
at usw.Weaver.WeaveAssembly(String assemblyPath, AssemblyDefinition unityEngineAssemblyDefinition, ReaderParameters readerParameters)
at usw.Weaver.Weave()
at usw.Program.RunProgram(ConversionOptions options)
at usw.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Here are my references in the project:

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Will master mode still reproduce this error?

Comment: @BarryWang yes, same same